# RegEx pattern to select all words between PowerShell parameters

Tags: regex, powershell

I have killed couple of hours and still can't get the regex right - I will really appreciate your help on this.

I need to match all the words between parameters, where the words to be selected are minimum two words separated by at least one space between two parameters (parameter is any word that starts with a dash: `-ParamName`) for example in the following string:

`Start-WinJob -ParamOne paramValue -ParamTwo`**`val1 val2 val3`**`-ParamThree`**`val1 val2 val3 valN`**

I need a regex expression to match:

**`val1 val2 val3`**

and

**`val1 val2 val3 valN`**

**UPDATE:**

I am using PowerShell and this snippet will print the matches on the console:

```
$pattern = "(?<= )\w+ [\w ]+" # referring to answeres below -> reset match using `\K` is not recognised in PowerShell implementation and errors
$text = "Start-WinJob -ParamOne paramValue -ParamTwo val1 val2 val3 -ParamThree val1 val2 val3 valN"
$text | Select-String $pattern -AllMatches | 
    % {$_.Matches} |
    % {$_.Value}
```

Guys you are awesome I find it really hard to choose the answer...
I want to throw a bit of extra complexity I hope you enjoy it - the matching values are speech sentenses. I am sorry for my omission, but I need to cater for punctuation charachters. Esentially any of these charachters: ``` €£$.%¬|@:?/,'#<>``&![]=-_)(*+ ``` could be present in the values and should not break the match of the values\words in addition duplicate double quote `""` should also be ignored

Updated test string :

`Start-WinJob -ParamOne paramValue -ParamTwo`**`val1 val2 val3`**`-ParamThree`**``` escape values: €£$.%¬|@?/,'#<>\``&![]=-_)(*+ lastVal ```**

Comment: What language or program are you planning to use this regex pattern in? Javascript, for example, doesn't support lookbehind, so that could limit what the pattern can do.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the language is obvious from the title - should work in PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can use lookbehind, this can be very simple:

`(?<= )\w+ [\w ]+`

https://regex101.com/r/Yqaajy/8

`(?<= )` Assert that the pattern is preceded by a space.

`\w+` - One or more word characters followed by a space.

`[\w ]+` - One more more word characters or spaces.

Comment: @CAstin, Thank you for your answer I really like the brevity of your suggestion! I also updated the question I wonder if you could suggest updated pattern - I apreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

### Brief

Since you haven't specified a language, I'll just assume *anything goes* in terms of regex.

---

### Code

[See this code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/WAbGF2/5)

```
-\w+\s+\K\w[\w\s]*(?=\s+-|$)
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
Start-WinJob -ParamOne paramValue -ParamTwoval val val3 -ParamThree val1 val2 val3 valN
```

#### Output

```
paramValue
val val3
val1 val2 val3 valN
```

---

### Explanation

- `-\w+\s+` Match `-` literally, followed by at least one word character (`a-zA-Z0-9_`), followed by at least one whitespace character
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the reported match (any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match)
- `\w[\w\s]*` Match any word character once, then any word character or whitespace character any number of times
- `(?=\s-|$)` Positive lookahead that ensures what follows is either one or more whitespace characters, followed by a `-` literally, or the end of the line

---

---

## Edit

### Code 1

[See code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/WAbGF2/6)

```
-\w+\s+\K(?:(?=\w+\s+\w)\w[\w\s]*)(?=\s+-|$)
```

Similarly, the code above simply checks that what follows contains any word, followed by a space, followed by any word character to ensure a minimum of two parameters is present.

### Code 2

[See this code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/WAbGF2/9)

```
-\w+\s+\K\w+\s+[\w\s]*(?=\s+-|$)
```

A shorter example of my first edit as suggested by [bulbus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6935152/bulbus) in the comments below.

Comment: Great usage of `\K` +1

Comment: Note that he/she doesn't want to match `paramValue` because it's only one parameter by itself.

Comment: `-\w+\s+\K\w+\s+[\w\s]*(?=\s+-|$)` updated your answer to match OP's request. https://regex101.com/r/WAbGF2/8

Comment: @ctwheels, thank you for your comprehensive answer! I also updated my question to clarify the language usage - I am sorry I used CAstins' pattern in the code snippet :) I only put it there for it's brevity, however I also added more complexity - I apreciate your help!

Comment: @ctwheels, unfortunatelly the reset match doen't not work in PowerShell, I get: `Select-String : The string -\w+\s+\K\w+\s+[\w\s]*(?=\s+-|$) is not a valid regular expression: parsing "-\w+\s+\K\w+\s+[\w\s]*(?=\s+-|$)" - Unrecognized escape sequence \K.
` you can use my script snippet in the updated answer to reproduce!